# Set ToggleSwitch On an Off

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, toggleswitch

I have 3 toggle switches named onlineToggle, offlineToggle, and maxToggle.

XAML:

```
<ToggleSwitch
x:Name="onlineToggleSwitch"
VerticalAlignment="Center"
FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
OffContent=""
OnContent=""
    PointerReleased="onlineToggleSwitch_PointerReleased">
</ToggleSwitch>

<ToggleSwitch
x:Name="offlineToggleSwitch"
VerticalAlignment="Center"
FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
OffContent=""
OnContent=""
    PointerReleased="offlineToggleSwitch_PointerReleased">
</ToggleSwitch>

<ToggleSwitch
x:Name="maxToggleSwitch"
VerticalAlignment="Center"
FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
OffContent=""
OnContent=""
    PointerReleased="maxToggleSwitch_PointerReleased">
</ToggleSwitch>
```

I want if onlineToggle isOn = true, then offlineToggle and maxToggle is off. If offlineToggle isOn = true, then onlineToggle and maxToggle are off. And if maxToggle isOn = true, then onlineToggle and offlineToggle are off.

Code:

```
private void onlineToggleSwitch_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    onlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = true;
    offlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
    maxToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
}

private async void offlineToggleSwitch_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
        onlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
        offlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = true;
        maxToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
}

private void maxToggleSwitch_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    onlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
    offlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
    maxToggleSwitch.IsOn = true;
}
```

But I have a problem, namely if onlineToggle isOn = true, then I want to change maxToggle = true, then toogleswitches are all off (maxToggle won't be on) like the video below:
https://1drv.ms/v/s!Av6G8Zq_Px8Whi9eSZTSDPqMUCdA?e=25cJtD

How to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you should want to select at most one of the three ToggleSwitchs.

It is recommended to use the [Toggled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.toggleswitch?view=winrt-22621#examples) event instead of the `PointerReleased` event. Determine whether the current ToggleSwitch  is `IsOn` in the event, and then close the other two ToggleSwitchs.

```
<ToggleSwitch
x:Name="onlineToggleSwitch"
VerticalAlignment="Center"
FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
OffContent=""
OnContent=""
  Toggled="onlineToggleSwitch_Toggled">
</ToggleSwitch>

<ToggleSwitch
x:Name="offlineToggleSwitch"
VerticalAlignment="Center"
FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
OffContent=""
OnContent=""
    Toggled="offlineToggleSwitch_Toggled">
</ToggleSwitch>

<ToggleSwitch
x:Name="maxToggleSwitch"
VerticalAlignment="Center"
FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
OffContent=""
OnContent=""
    Toggled="maxToggleSwitch_Toggled">
</ToggleSwitch>
```

---

```
private void onlineToggleSwitch_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     
     if (onlineToggleSwitch.IsOn == true)
     {
         offlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
         maxToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
     }
 }

 private void offlineToggleSwitch_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    
     if (offlineToggleSwitch.IsOn == true)
     {
         onlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
         maxToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
     }
     
 }

 private void maxToggleSwitch_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (maxToggleSwitch.IsOn == true)
     {
         onlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
         offlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
     }
    
 }
```

Comment: If I use this code, then when the onlineToggle position is on and I set maxToggle to on, then onlineToggle and maxToggle become on, whereas what I want is maxToggle to be on and onlineToggle to be off (so only one of the toggleSwitches is on).

Comment: Have you deleted your original code? My test results https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv7gX.gif

Answer (score 0):

You're using the "wrong" controls for this scenario; RadioButtons are more appropriate when only one control in a "group" can be selected. ToggleSwitch is not a "group" item. With more than one option, then CheckBoxes are more appropriate.

In either case (RB or CB), you can then just deal with the Click / Checked event; instead of having to decipher what caused the "toggle" in this case.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the behavior you described, you can modify your event handlers to check the state of the toggle switches before changing their values. Here's how you can do it:

```
private void onlineToggleSwitch_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!onlineToggleSwitch.IsOn)
    {
        onlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = true;
        offlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
        maxToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
    }
    else if (maxToggleSwitch.IsOn)
    {
        onlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
        offlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
        maxToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
    }
}

private void offlineToggleSwitch_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!offlineToggleSwitch.IsOn)
    {
        onlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
        offlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = true;
        maxToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
    }
    else if (maxToggleSwitch.IsOn)
    {
        onlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
        offlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
        maxToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
    }
}

private void maxToggleSwitch_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!maxToggleSwitch.IsOn)
    {
        onlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
        offlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
        maxToggleSwitch.IsOn = true;
    }
    else
    {
        onlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
        offlineToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
        maxToggleSwitch.IsOn = false;
    }
}
```

This modification will ensure that when you try to switch maxToggleSwitch on while onlineToggleSwitch is already on, all switches will be turned off. Similarly, it will handle the cases for other switches as well.

Comment: It doesn't work and the problem above still occurs